# DeepClone issues with protobuf-net - using enums

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

i have a class which is decorated with DataContract and ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields), one of the members and properties is Enum. i am trying to deepclone the object however when the source has in the enum member the value which is mapped to value 0, after the clone i am getting the default value

The class is:

```
public enum A {
    A0 = 0,
    A1 = 1,
    A2 = 2
}
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
public class Ac {
    private A _aa = A.A2;
    public string sa { get; set; }
    public A aa { get { return _aa; } set { _aa = value; } }
}
```

With serialization code:

```
Ac a1 = new Ac();
a1.sa = "dfdf";
a1.aa = A.A0;
Ac a2 = new Ac();
a2.sa = "dfdf";
a2.aa = A.A1;
var sa1 = Serializer.DeepClone<Ac>(a1);
var sa2 = Serializer.DeepClone<Ac>(a2);
```

Comment: is it possible that value 0 is used as default and ignored at desirializetion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For legacy reasons, protobuf-net uses an "implicit zero defaults" behavior. Something I regret from v1 but there we are. The implicit default is therefore `0` === `A0`. You can, however, re-educate it:

```
[DefaultValue(A.A2)]
private A _aa = A.A2;
```

(i.e. tell the system what your constructor is going to do)

Alternatively, if you are content that you understand your protobuf-net usage - you can change this behavior:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
```

in which case only explicit default (`[DefaultValue]` and conditional patterns such as `ShouldSerialize*` / `*Specified`) are processed.

Comment: basically in the full solution i am using runtime type model for the inheritance - i will check it now, thanks

Comment: even after adding default value i am getting same behavior , also tried Default.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false; on the runtime model

Comment: can SkipConstructor = true help?

Comment: @li-raz that would prevent the field initializers and constructor from running, so yes it would probably "fix" it, but for different reasons - not sure I'd recommend that. I tested your code locally just using `[DefaultValue(A.A2)]` - it worked fine...